# Exclude rows that have same value in two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has 2 columns that sometimes have the same values. I want to know how to exclude the rows where the value of column1 is equal to a value in column2.

EXAMPLE:

```
COL1   |    COL2

1  --------  7  
2  --------  8    
3  --------  2
4  --------  5    
5  --------  9
```

Here I would exclude rows 2 and 5.
Thanks

Comment: [what have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   * 
from table
where col1 not in (
   select 
       column2 
   from table
)
```

Comment: What if there is more than the 2 columns in the table but you still want to exclude rows where column1 is equal to a value in column2 ?

Comment: the where clause compares col1 and col2 only so it would not matter how many columns are in the table

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE COL1 NOT IN (SELECT COL2 
                   FROM yourtable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to avoid using IN for long lists of values, as it performs poorly on some database systems. The following selects all values from col1 that are not present in col2:

```
SELECT col1 
FROM
  yourtable t1
  LEFT JOIN
  yourtable t2
  ON 
    t1.col1 = t2.col2
WHERE
  t2.col2 IS NULL
```

Why does it work? Well, normally the join operator will link together rows that have the same value. Left join will keep some rows that are mismatched though (and it's those we want). The left join takes the table on the left (t1) and uses it as the reference table, and starts associating rows from the table on the right (after the word JOIN, in this case t2). If the col1 value has a matching value in col2 then the row will be fully populated with values for each. If the value from col1 has no matching value from col2, the col2 cell on the resulting row is blank/null. Because we hence want to know only those values that aren't matched, we say "where col2 is null"

The other trick with getting to grips with this is in understanding that the same table can appear twice in a query. We give it a different alias each time we use it so we can tell them apart. You could conceive it as virtually making a copy of the table, before it links them together

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Debatable because left join matches and selects all rows and then filters. Not in filters every row right from start. An execution plan would show which is best for the db.

Comment: Short and sweet! The only thing I'll add is to add separate indices for each column if your table doesn't already have it.

Comment: @goose here's every chance that the optimiser would choose a full table scan followed by a hash (essentially building an index on the fly) so indexes might be ignored. The same could well apply to an IN based query, of course; different optimisers plan these things in different ways. In my past experience, Oracle was worse with iN than JOiN. Sqlserver seems better; perhaps MS put more effort into recognising and rewriting queries to be equivalent whether they use IN or JOiN, though I've long felt "do not use IN for lists longer than you would type by hand" is a good rule of thumb

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXCEPT` together with a correlated sub-query - as shown below.

> Read up on EXCEPT here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST

EXCEPT 

SELECT *
FROM TEST
WHERE COL1 IN (
    SELECT COL2
    FROM TEST
)
```

Comment: Theoretically, IN should work better than NOT IN; however, I also used EXCEPT, which may outweigh any gain which I may have had by avoiding a NOT IN. I have not tested this with a large data set (as in north of 1M rows) - are they getting the same execution plan? If so, go with the NOT IN, as it is smaller, shorter and easier to read. In a case where you have no performance gain between two methods, it is always better to use the easier-to-read version.

Answer (score -1):

not sure, but maybe...

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM my_table AS t1
LEFT JOIN my_table AS t2
     ON t2.col_b = t1.col_a
WHERE t2.col_b IS NULL
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Put 4 spaces at the start of every line having code. I approve of this method over IN..